# How to Store Obtained Packet into a variable for pkt.show() command?

Tags: python, scapy

I wanted to store the Raw packet obtained through sniff command of scapy and use it further.
How can I do this?

I could print data on command prompt but unable to store it.

This is my code:

```
def pkt_callback(pkt):
    self.S = pkt.show()         
    self.P = sniff(count = self.C, filter="udp", prn = pkt_callback)
```

When I run this code I receive data but unable to store them

I expect to store load/ Raw data into a variable

```
load = '\x17\x03\x01\x01`\ngD\xdb/\xe5m!jEm\xe1%\x88\xa9~ *y\xcc\xd1T\xb6Vg\xb3\x82\\\x00\x91\r\xc1\xe4\xe0\xdb\xa2|\xc2\x86\xa2\x99J0\x86V\xc5\xad}y\xb4k&\x1e$\xcb\xcc\x99\xe0\xdb\xcf<\x1e\xc1\x10ZD\xc5\x8b\xaa\xa0\x0c\x08\xc4\xa1\xa0&\xd6.\x1f\
```

but unable to do it.

Comment: Looks like you should start off with the doc :) https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have gone through the document. But no where I found how to store a result. If I simply store the result it gives a null output. Please suggest.

Comment: `self.S = pkt.load`

Comment: I am unable to get any output using this command.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer which worked for me, hoping this might help someone:

```
    pkts = sniff(count =self.c,filter = "dst host %s or src host %s and udp" % (self.dst, self.src))

    pkt = pkts[0]          

    pkt_raw = raw(pkt)
    print("Raw packet data",pkt_raw)
```

found the solution from https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/scapy/stable/scapy.pdf